# emulator virtual device not booting; log shows 'unknown error'

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to start an android virtual device with the emulator on an old XP SP2 desktop.
The device comes up with a blank screen and does not even show the initial android logo. I checked previous posts and possibly [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580) is similar but unanswered.
So here goes -I started the emulator on cmd prompt with verbose option and I see unknown error
reported:

> emulator: Realistic sensor emulation is not available, since the
>   remote controll er is not accessible:  Unknown error emulator:
>   emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>
> emulator: Could not open file: ÿ-": No such file or directory
>   emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
>   emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server

Incidentally adb does not list the device. The device buttons respond to mouse but screen remains blank and as I said earlier I dont see it come up with the boot screen. I also tried powering on using the power button but with no luck. I should add I also created a couple of devices with different names but with no change.

Any pointers on how to fix greatly appreciated.