# Android Emulator Stuck With Black Screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm just new with Android Development, and running the default blank project. I have Android Studio 2.1.2.
The problem is the emulator stuck with the black screen although HAXM works well:
"HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode"
Most solutions suggest to uncheck "use host gpu" in AVD Manager, yet it seems this feature no longer appear in the new version of Android Studio.
I run macOS El Capitan.

Answer (score 5):

After an update to Android Studio this weekend (maybe Gradle?), the AVD emulator (Mac) suddenly started showing a black screen when I ran my installed app APK. Sometimes it showed a blue screen. Sometimes the emulator even showed a page of installed app icons. Sometimes upside down. Sometimes upside down and reversed! That smelled like a graphics problem.

Thanks to audio in my app, I realized I could still activate buttons in my app by clicking on a specific location of the black screen. Definitely a graphics problem.

Based on other ideas that I read, **I edited my AVD device config in the Emulated Performance section, to change Graphics from "Automatic" to "Software - GLES 2.0"**.

It worked for me on the emulators for Nexus 9 and Pixel XL on API 25.

This solution does **not** work on Play Store-enabled devices because the Graphics setting can't be changed. For example the Nexus 5X API 25.

Environment: Android Studio 3.0.1, Gradle 4.1

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Increase the RAM size to 2.5GB in Advance settings of Emulator. Black Screen will be gone.
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I got stuck with black screen in the emulator is that I needed to update my Android SDK Tools. Hope this could help someone get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the emulator was updated in studio 2.1.3, can you update and see if you have the exact problem?

download is here, 2nd set of links:

http://tools.android.com/

Comment: Downloading is in progress, hoping it's gonna solve the issue. thank you @Grott.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting CPU/ABI with Intel Atom(x86_64) (when creat a emulator or editing a emulator) worked for me.

[image]