# Android Device Monitor will not launch, either from Android Studio or from Terminal -- UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, android-studio, osx-elcapitan, ddms, android-device-monitor

I am getting the following error when trying to launch Android Device Monitor from the Tools window in Android Studio on a Mac.

[image]

and when I open the log file I find an error report very similar to the other SO questions similar to this, esp [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526596/android-device-monitor-doesnt-open-error-on-log-file?noredirect=1&lq=1).  However, using sudo did not work for me, although I get similar, though much shorter, error data:

```
Macs-MBP:tools macuser$ sudo ./monitor
Password:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/archquery/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
./monitor: line 41: /Users/macuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/monitor-/monitor.app/Contents/MacOS/monitor: No such file or directory
./monitor: line 41: exec: /Users/macuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/monitor-/monitor.app/Contents/MacOS/monitor: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Backstory: After doing a complete, new Android Studio installation on this laptop (El Capitan) I attempted to launch the monitor from inside the IDE. It complained that running it required Java 1.6.  So I installed Java 6. Then when I tried it I got the error message above.

I get the following when I ran from Terminal java_home -V

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The contents of the log file are (unfortunately had to cull some because of text entry limitations for post):

```
!SESSION 2017-03-07 14:46:16.923 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/macuser/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault -keyring /Users/macuser/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.397
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.400
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.401
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.424
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.425
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.425
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.426
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.429
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.430
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.430
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.431
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.432
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:17.924
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor (4).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin for bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin.<clinit>(MonitorPlugin.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    ... 33 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.018
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.018
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.018
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.018
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.018
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.018
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.018
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.037
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.037
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721 [24] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.037
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.037
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.037
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.highlighter_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.037
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.memory_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.037
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.queries_[2.9.1,3.0.0).

. . .

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-07 14:46:18.041
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin for bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin.<clinit>(MonitorPlugin.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. Based on the log file, the new version of Android Studio requires Java 8 "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0": [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

I'm running Linux, I currently have java8 installed so I just needed to use:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

and

```
update-alternatives --config javac
```

then everything worked.

It looks as though you're using a Mac, so you may or may not need to do the following after installing Java 8: [Installed Java 7 on Mac OS X but Terminal is still using version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-os-x-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6)

Info from [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0) source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)

- **J2SE 8 = *52***
- J2SE 7 = 51
- J2SE 6.0 = 50
- J2SE 5.0 = 49
- JDK 1.4 = 48
- JDK 1.3 = 47
- JDK 1.2 = 46
- JDK 1.1 = 45

Comment: James, we're closer I think.  I installed Java 8 successfully it seems (at the end of the process it confirmed it was installed), but looks like my system is still using Java 6.  I'm trying to figure out how to get it where when I run Android Device Monitory it doesn't say "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0".  The problem still seems to be the same, but java -version says I'm using Java 6 still.

Comment: This was the solution, thanks.  My mistake was to install only the JRE for 1.8.  When I realized this and installed the SDK the problems all went away.

Comment: Alyoshak, GREAT! Glad I could help.

Comment: Wonderful! This has fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score 7):

Confusingly I didn't have Java 8 installed in a shared location (only the bundled version in Android Studio). Installing it through homebrew solved my problem.

```
brew cask install java

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio comes with built-in Java 1.8, so it wasn't a problem when you are developing android app. But when you launch Android Device Monitor, it uses external java compiler that run on your OS. If you have preinstalled Java before, it won't be a problem. Otherwise, you will face the same problem.

I tried to set JAVA_HOME path to java packed in Android Studio. It does not work, probably because it is openjdk version.

My solution was to download Java JDK 1.8 from Oracle and install in my computer.

Comment: You should have set the PATH, not the JAVA_HOME environmental variable. That way, it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the particular error message you will see the first few line of the error message as below.

```
!SESSION 2017-12-20 08:17:02.597 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
```

This is what I got. I have installed both java 8 and 9 in my mac and made java 8 as the default. According to the error message java virtual device took java 9 but its need 8. Thats where the probelm happened.So I uninstalled the java 9 from my machine then its started to work fine.

Comment: Worked for me, however I didn't need to uninstall previous version just installed over it I guess

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Win10 + JDK 12 + Android Sdk. When I ran "monitor.bat", it is the exactly the same problem. I guess monitor application can not reconginize the latest java version naming convention.
I install JRE 8(as follows), the problem is gone.

`c:\>java -version
 java version "1.8.0_221"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)`

Comment: It's working!. In my case, I use OpenJDK 14 and it's not working. But after I installed Oracle JDK 8, it's working!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work for me. I'm using JAVA8, both the Android `JAVA_HOME` and `/usr/bin/java`. What is weirder for me is my tools/ directory is missing the `uiautomationviewer` tool as well. So it made me wonder if something went wrong during the installation.

What I ended up doing was downloading an older verion of SDK-tools
(I followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043655)), and replaced the entire sdk/tools folder. And it worked....

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was observed on:
macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Android Studio 3.0.1

Was solved by:
**Uninstalling** Java SE Development Kit 8u**152**
And **Installing** Java SE Development Kit **8u151**
from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click sdk/tools/monitor.bat and Click "run as administrator"