# Android Emulator not starting on Windows XP

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, windows-xp

On windows xp, when i start the android emulator through eclipse, it displays the "Starting emulator for Blank" screen, but when it finishes loading, the emulator window does not come up. I tried to start the emulator at least 5 times, and i have tried deleting the emulator and making a new one, but the new one didn't work either.

Comment: May be you get help from 

[Android emulator shows nothing except black screen and adb devices shows “device offline”][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device

Comment: No... it doesn't even make a new window, and I also checked the task manager; there is nothing there either.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing Genymotion

> http://www.genymotion.com/

this works really fine

Comment: Working well so far, haven't started a virtual device yet.