# Emulator not working with Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I am facing problem with Android 5.0 emulator. I need to test my app into lollipop environment. I downloaded sdk tools and all images for test environment . I created emulators with almost all images but emulator running blank screen with android text on it. how do I resolve this issue.

Please help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device use this link.

Comment: I Tried all the ways mentioned in the link .. but nothing worked for me. I am using ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by downloading latest sdk tools and platform tools from sdk manager. Previously sdk manager not displaying latest sdks till we install latest toos but in case of lollipop we are able to download with out having latest sdk tool but facing Emulator issues,