# Can't start emulator for Android Studio

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio, the new official IDE for Android. I can't never get the emulator running.

A black emulator screen containing the word "android" flashing appears, without change for minutes. I have waited more than 30 minutes without any change.

Must I use eclipse instead?

The IDE shows the messages:

```
Waiting for device. C:\Users\Yasser\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe
-avd Nexus7 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android emulator shows nothing except black screen and adb devices shows "device offline"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are getting blank screen So try to create an emulator with `uncheck Use Host Gpu`.

You can follow this step for creating new Emulator..

Click on `Create virtual device` , select `Phone` than choose `Nexus 5` from list and select `Lollipop` with `api 21` and `Target Android 5.0` . On next Page `uncheck Use Host Gpu` and press `Finish` .

try and let me know if still you are facing same issue..

Comment: im sorry but i cant find the Create Virtual device button