# Why is the Android emulator screen blank?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I have recently installed Android Studio and all its updates using sdks manager. When I try to start the emulator i can see this:

> emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

It seems good. The emulator start but only thing i can see is a black screen.
I use the default AVD created by the app. It has google api's x86 system image, 1gb ram, 64mb vm heap and 200mb intel storage.
I tried to uncheck "Use Host GPU" but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: check answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567007/cant-start-emulator-for-android-studio/27569946#27569946

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android emulator shows nothing except black screen and adb devices shows "device offline"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device)

Answer (score 57):

I have recently the same issue in emulator, Nexus 5 (Android O). I have go to Android Virtual Device Manager and Wipe User Data and it solved my Problem.

[image]

Comment: This fix the issue for me, Thanks

Comment: Selecting 'Cold Boot' from the dropdown in 'Actions' worked for me

Comment: Fixed it for me too - thanks

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same your issue, this is what I did that works:
My one starts working with Nexus_4_API_25 (tried even with Nexus 6, Nexus 5 and Nexus One none of them was working!!)
Create a new ADV from Android Studio ( bare in mind that i didn't allow the new front and rear camera to the new device, so switch them off)
So go to Terminal and go to the folder where your emulator is and lists your emulators, my one:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds
```

After run your emulator with the gpu hosted on your machine:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_25 -gpu host
```

It will start the emulator and then you can run your app in it.
Hopefully this can helps someone else.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue, and what solved it for me was unchecking everything that has to do with snapshots.

I assume that my snapshot was corrupt somehow.

Uncheck loading and saving to snapshots.

Comment: For me isn't this the problem. Loading and saving to snapshots was already unchecked.

Answer (score 3):

I'm embarrassed to say I lost too much time before I realized I just needed to click the Power Button to wake it up.

Comment: Same! And with the way my tool window was sized and positioned, the Power button wasn't even visible on the toolbar

Comment: oh my god... I this issue troubled me for hours! What stupid power buttion is it?

Comment: You would think it would be on by default like it is in IOS simulator... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue,
I solved by reducing the AVD version. In the AVD manager choose create a lower version e.g. I was using Nexus 5 and created a Nexus 4 which worked well.

If this solves it means you need to upgrade your machine, RAM etc.

Comment: Made no difference, still get the black screen.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me, I solved it by using x86_64 system image instead of x84, maybe x86 image has some bug on some host system, e.g. Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at your skins - some have found it works with the WVGA800 skin. 
Others here have found it's due to the high RAM requirements of the Nexus 5 AVD itself. I think Nexus 5 takes almost 1600. Try either decreasing the RAM allocation in the AVD ('Advanced settings')  -  or reinstall HAXM with a higher RAM limit.

Answer (score 1):

if you have avast antivirus installed
 In Avast antivirus under Settings (parametres) tab > Troubleshooting (depannage), you should uncheck "Enable Hardware-assisted Virtualization" ("activer l'assistance a la virtualisation").

Now restart your computer it should work
if not re-install the Intel's HAXM which can be found under ~SDK_LOCATION\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that the x86 emulator would hang during startup (black screen, no logo). The answer to my problem had to do with me using Eclipse ADT with an old SDK prior to upgrading to Android Studio on the same computer.

I am running Ubuntu and the configuration files are stored in the .android folder of the home directory, i.e. ~/.android. I saw references to the old SDKs in the config files and deleted the whole folder. After that the x86 emulator started working again.

In hindsight, what gave it away was that when I started using ARM images the emulator worked. I had only used x86 images with qemu in the past.

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution of that things is that
switching graphics mode it really help you [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also got same issue but wipe the Android Emulator and relaunched worked but only thing is we need to do again setup for all previous settings

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this after running a long overdue upgrade to Android Studio, where existing settings were imported into the upgrade.

Getting all the SDK updates was not enough.  The issue was finally resolved after Invalidate-Cache & Restart

Answer (score 0):

Put Graphics in SOFTWARE in the emulator configuration, it worked for me.