# android emulator bug black screen in Debian 8

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I have a problem with android emulator in ***Debian 8 amd64***.

After a few minutes in operation , it will be black and will not receive any more commands.

*Just remember that it is no use installing the Intel Hardware Accelerator because it is not compatible with linux.*

A screenshot with details for ***Nexus_5_API_23*** was attachment below:

[image: screenshot Details for Nexus_5_API_23]

The last monitoring logs are below:

```
12-15 09:52:02.675 2239-2469/com.android.phone E/DcSwitchStateMachine-0: EVENT_DATA_DISALLOWED failed, com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
12-15 09:52:02.690 2239-2239/com.android.phone D/MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration mccmnc='310260' fromServiceState=false
12-15 09:52:02.732 2239-2239/com.android.phone D/MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration defaultMccMnc=310260
12-15 09:52:02.732 2239-2239/com.android.phone D/MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration: mcc=310, mnc=260
12-15 09:52:02.732 2239-2239/com.android.phone D/MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration updateConfig config={1.0 310mcc260mnc ?locale ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
12-15 09:52:02.736 1714-1784/system_process W/WindowManager: Timeout waiting for drawn: undrawn=[Window{6c7f4b1 u0 StatusBar}]
12-15 09:52:03.242 1714-1784/system_process W/WindowManager: Window freeze timeout expired.
12-15 09:52:03.242 1714-1784/system_process W/WindowManager: Force clearing orientation change: Window{11680f u0 NavigationBar}
12-15 09:52:03.242 1714-1784/system_process W/WindowManager: Force clearing orientation change: Window{6c7f4b1 u0 StatusBar}
12-15 09:52:03.521 1714-1784/system_process I/SystemServiceManager: Starting phase 1000
12-15 09:52:03.528 2035-2035/com.android.systemui W/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: invalid subId in handleSimStateChange()
12-15 09:52:03.781 2485-2549/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.partnersetup.rlzappprovider
12-15 09:52:03.851 2239-2282/com.android.phone W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(long, long) from SQLiteConnection.java:4294967294 waiters=0 for 321ms
12-15 09:52:03.863 2035-2035/com.android.systemui W/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: invalid subId in handleServiceStateChange()
12-15 09:52:03.884 1714-2237/system_process I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder_5 expire 10 lines
```

**References:**

[android emulator black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864774/android-emulator-black-screen)

Please, I need your help.

Thanks for everything, right away.

.

#### EDIT - Upgrade the Android-sdk

For long time, I stopped programming on Android, but now that I came back, I found the solution, just upgrade the Android-sdk version and use the updated emulator.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am seeing the same warnings.

Comment: I'm using now `android-28`.

Comment: You can upgrade your Android-sdk and find the same solution :)