# Android Studio Emulators not Working after Updating emulator on 11/13/18

Tags: android, emulation

I accepted a recommended emulator update in Android Studio about 10 minutes ago (11/13/18, 7:20 AM PST).
Now the emulator will not boot up.  It starts, but I just get a black screen and it does not boot Android.  This is the case on all of my emulated devices.
I have done some research such as posted here: [stackoverflow.com/q/27864774/1531971](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27864774/1531971) 
For each case, I either tried them or they are not relevant to my situation.
All of my emulators were working fine before the emulator update.
Now it just says "waiting for target device to come online" and it never comes online. There are no error messages.  I'm running Windows 7.  Is anyone else having this problem?  Please help.

Comment: What research have you done? For example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/27864774/1531971

Comment: Thanks I checked these.  For each case, I either tried them or they are not relevant to my situation.

Comment: Then you need to say so in the text of the question with an [Edit]. Don't make people who want to help you go over the same ground.

Comment: Seems as though there are many causes of same symptom - one solution that I found applied in my case after update was this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44535135/2711811.