# The AVD "OK" button disable

Tags: java, android

I using android studio and having problem with creating new AVD. i already insert all the detail needed but the "OK" button cannot be clicked. i already install the system image but still cant create. can anyone help me?

Comment: please add a screenshot for the same

Comment: Please post more details what you want or Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567007/cant-start-emulator-for-android-studio/27569946#27569946

Comment: It wont be visible until the emulator you made supports that particular api level. Try to reduce the api level if it works.