# Android Studio Emulator: emulator shows only "android" text

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-emulator

I am learning Android with tutorial from his page, and I have problem in part: [Running Your App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) chapter. When I see `activity_my.xml` preview I see "Hello world" text, but when I run application and see emulated device, emulator shows device with only black page and "android" text. I think I can't start it properly, but in Android Studio console I see:

```
C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe 
-avd Nexus_4_cale -netspeed full -netdelay none

creating window 208 44 800 480
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

So it seems to be ok. But if I choose to edit "app" configuration, in `Target Device / Emulator` I see that `Prefer Adroid Virtual Device`, in my calse, called "Nexus_4_cale", is red. But if I edit this device there is no errors etc.. I don't know what's happening, and I will be happy if anybody would like to help me with this problem - thank you in advance.

That is how it looks in emulator:
[image: Emulator]

And that is how it looks in Android Studio preview:
[image: Preview_in_IDE]

And that is configuration, with red device but with no explanation:
[image: configuration]

Code for `activity_my.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MyActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And code for `MyActivity.java` class:

```
package com.example.abc.android3;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

All code is generated by Android Studio

Comment: It is unclear exactly what is happening, and what you are trying to fix. Please add more information. Perhaps add screenshots, and post the relevant code (java, xml)

Comment: @Zerp I'll do it in few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in Loading.. You have to wait for loading to complete. If still your emulator is not starting  than edit your `emulator` configuration by `uncheck Use Host Gpu` For more check [Can't start emulator for Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567007/cant-start-emulator-for-android-studio/27569946#27569946)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time - it is loading view, but it was so slow... Over 20 minutes until I saw something and it was reason that I thought something is wrong - simply I wait a little more time and saw what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing any errors and you are using Mac. Make sure you don't have Docker up and running. The moment I turned off Docker, it all worked. Can't believe the 2 hours I spent for the debugging.