# Running AVD is giving error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-virtual-device

Command I'm running:

> ```
> C:\Users\bhaishaki\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86
> ```

```
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

Comment: At a guess I would say add `'-gpu off'` to your command line to disable OpenGLES emulation!

Comment: I am new learner.Please give me a descriptive solution.

Comment: Sure thing - try running this: `C:\Users\bhaishaki\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -gpu off -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86`

Comment: The problem resolved with multiple options here!!


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while Running Android Application - Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Android Studio, launch the AVD Manager, edit the Nexus AVD (ie. click the pencil icon), and in the resulting window, uncheck the "Use Host GPU" checkbox.

That fixed the error for me and allowed me to launch the emulator from Android Studio.

Comment: Couldn't find this option in android studio 2.1.2

Answer (score 3):

check those links : [Emulator!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824761/problems-launching-the-emulator-in-android-studio/31042823#31042823) and [Emulator!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567007/cant-start-emulator-for-android-studio/27569946#27569946).

Note: Edit emulator  `Uncheck 'Use Host GPU' option.` . Still any prob just let me know

Answer (score 3):

Following answer will be for android 2.0 and above users

Once you choose "Software - GLES 2.0" everything will be fine.

STEPS:

```
1)Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager 
2)Select "Edit" ( a green pencil like icon).
3)Select "Show Advanced Settings".
4)In the Graphics drop list select "Software - GLES 2.0"
5)Click finish to save and now again build the gradle.
```

Below image shows the setting which I had to remove the error.
[image: For further reference]

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you downloaded the packages required by the api level of your selected device.

I advice you to open SDK manager and check whether the required Api packages are installed or not .

Answer (score 2):

Go to AVD Manager.
- Edit your AVD.
- Uncheck 'Use Host GPU' option.
- Click Finish (Save).
- Start AVD again.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your AVD ,On Graphics select Software-GLES instead of Auto.Its worked for me.I am also updated VM heap size to 384 in advanced settings option.