# Error while Running Android Application - Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-virtual-device

I am new to android programming. I was referring google developer website to learn android. While I was running an application UI, I got these errors.

```
 H:\SDK\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
 emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to   disable it.
 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
 could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
 getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
 Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
 Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

I am using android studio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567007/cant-start-emulator-for-android-studio/27569946#27569946

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124858/android-studio-emulator-could-not-find-wglgetextensionsstringarb/40125067#40125067

Comment: Use `emulator.exe @Nexus_6p.API.25 -gpu off`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I recently faced the same issue, The problem occurs because AVD tries to render graphics using system's graphics card and could not do that either because your system's graphics driver is not up to date or it does not support this so here is the solution.

**Step 1:**

- Update your Operating system graphics driver.
- Restart your system.
- Set your system's screen resolution as high as possible.
- Try to start your AVD now.

**Step 2:**

- If step 1 fails, Go to AVD Manager.
- Edit your AVD.
- Uncheck 'Use Host GPU' option.
- Click Finish (Save).
- Start AVD again.

Comment: Worked for me, I unchecked the "Use Host GPU" option. Thanks. Up voted this answer!

Comment: Alternative to Step1 might be - disabling some GPU and/or monitor in case you have multiple GPUs, like in my case ATI FireMV(old) and IntelHD(new, onboard). Disabling ATI has resolved it for me. Hope this comment will help someone.

Comment: for step 2 using AS 3.x, no such "Use Host GPU" option. But "Hardware - GLES 2.0" not work either.

Comment: Worked for me just i enable my Intel Graphics Driver and its running now. Thanks

Answer (score 103):

- Go to AVD Manager.
- Edit your AVD.
- Select 'Software GLES2.0' option on Emulated Performance.
  (The reason is because some users did not install graphic video card drivers )
- Click Finish (Save).
- Start AVD again.
  [image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me so much time

Comment: Thanks, Lester !! This small thing took my whole day. But the error message was bit complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me so much time (2).

Answer (score 6):

While configuring new device, use the option "Software - GLES 2.0" for Graphics under "Emulated Performance" category. This option will be seen once you click "Show Advanced Settings" while configuring AVD.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this, and it was because I running via Windows Remote Desktop. When I logged on locally it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you run your AVD manager not from eclipse go to installed directory that is android/AVD manager.exe and right click run as administrator and then make changes.

Comment: Hello @4D - Problem Solver 1-what your meaning of update graphic driver? Does it much memory of graphic card or some software issue. and second I disable -gpu host option but my emulator still not running.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem on my laptop which runs Windows 10 and has two GPUs: one within the Intel processor and the other is Nvidia. The error appears when the system uses the low performance Intel GPU. I needed to "run" Android Studio with "High performance NVIDIA processor"
Most of the programs can be run with NVIDIA by right clicking the application link and then "Run with graphics processor" and then "High-performance NVIDIA processor"

Unfortunately this didn't work with the Android Studio application link for me. I had to go to Settings > Display > Graphics settings > Browse and then choose the Android Studio executable (studio and then studio64, I did it for the both of them)
Then the application appear just under the Browse button, select the application, then Options, then select High performance.