# How to improve the performance of emulator in Android studio?

Tags: android-emulator

Whenever I run my small application in Android studio it takes more time to boot in emulator .

My system config as follows

- RAM 4GB
- PROCESSOR dual core
- GPU intel integrated graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel’s x86 Emulator Accelerator Manager  allows developers to run an emulator which performs much faster than a typical emulator running on an ARM-based CPU architecture. It should be noted that this technology only works on Intel VT (Virtualization Technology) enabled systems.You can also enable your emulator to use your machine’s GPU which should make rendering of animations or graphics much faster than it would otherwise be.

Comment: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable...facing this problem

Comment: emulator is working fine for API version 15 and below but its not getting booted above API 15...i have tried and checking host GPU..

Comment: should need to Change my processor dual core to i3 processor to work on higher version of API???

Comment: Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:488
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentere...

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) driver? This makes the emulator usable but even then there is room for performance improvements...
(Of course your graphic card driver should be installed properly)

Comment: i downloaded and i'm facing this problem now.."Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable"

Comment: What OS are you using? You should properly install your graphic drivers... And maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio

Comment: Did you install an up-to-date driver? Otherwise try to disable the graphic hardware acceleration: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics

Comment: emulator is working fine for API version 15 and below but its not getting booted above API 15...i have tried and checking host GPU..

Comment: should need to Change my processor dual core to i3 processor to work on higher version API???