# android studio failed to create drawable

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run the emulator in Android Studio. When I run the avd for Nexus 5 API 8, the phone image appears, but the screen is blank. Some research uncovered that the nexus screen may be too dense to display on my 1368x768 laptop screen, so I tried creating smaller density avds such as 4" wvga nexus s and 3.4" wvga. When I run these, I get the error "failed to create drawable" and no phone image pops up. When I connect my LG phone via usb in developer mode, the app works fine on the phone. Why can't I get the emulator to display the app output?

Comment: Because either the emulator or your computer is garbage; try using GenyMotion, it works fine on alot of low-end specs, as did AndroVM.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and the solution was to disable hardware rendering.

Steps:

- Open Tools\Android\AVD Manager
- Edit the Virtual Device (Click on the pencil)
- Change Emulated Performance - Graphics to 'Software-GLES 2.0'

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio) answer for other options.