# emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored

Tags: android

I am getting this error when I tired launching the emulator. Any suggestions?

**emulator WARNING:**

> Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
>   Could not load func glBindFramebuffer
>   Could not load func glGenFramebuffers
>   Could not load func glFramebufferTexture2D
>   Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus
>   Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers
>   Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer
>   Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer
>   Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers
>   Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers
>   Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage
>   Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
>   Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer

Comment: I hope this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio

Answer (score 1):

From Android Studio blog:
Android Studio now uses CPU acceleration on x86 emulator system images by default. Combined with new Symmetric Multi-Processor (SMP) support in Android 6.0 Marshmallow system images, the Android emulators can perform even faster than many physical Android devices. Multi-core support not only makes your apps and the emulator run faster but it provides the added advantage of speeding up common developer tasks such as installing APKs. Also, with SMP you can test apps that specifically target multi-processor Android devices.

So you need x86 system image of Marshmallow.

Comment: and.. ?   What if we want to run Lollipop or less, is there a config setting to adjust in the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Please update your SDK Tools. This is my way.

Answer (score 0):

This may be entirely unrelated, but I solved this issue by unchecking Snapshot and ticking Use Host GPU in the Virtual Device settings. After this the AVD started correctly and the error was no longer present.