# Unable to start emulator on Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am unable to start my emulator on **Android Studio 2.1** and getting the following **error**:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 48MB
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Could not initialize emulated framebufferaudio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

Getting same error in the *console* of **AVD**

I am trying to run with this following **configurations** :
[image: Emulator Config]

My *android-studio has the following details*:
[image: About android studio]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have same problem.  Tried each of the two answers (raise & lower device RAM).  Also tried adjusting HAXM memory down from 2Gb default to 1.5 Gb (just in case my 8Gb lap top was having RAM issues).   Results not consistent.   Fresh reboot first of day sometimes I can get AVD running API 23 just fine, amazingly fast program patch changes. Just enough to make me hopeful for AVD.  Then reality hits - "emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 48MB"   I did not set that!.   All latest AS & SDK updates, images Win 7 Pro 64bit 8gb ram.

Comment: Had same kind of issues with AVD and one thing is sure that it has something to do with your graphical card. 1) One of the workarounds you'll see is to force software rendering, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio) for example, but it will make your VM run slow. 2) Maybe like in my case: I have two graphical cards ATI FireMV which is very old and IntelHD. Disabling ATI resolved it for me and emulator is running in hardware-accelerated mode(=fast). Hope it wil help someone.

Comment: go through this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653391/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator-android-studio-2-1

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem and this is how I resolved it

1. Select your AVD manager
2. Select your device from the list of your virtual devices
3. Click Edit this device information
4. Click show advance settings
5. Change the Ram size to 1 GB and click finish
6. launch your emulator

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Try enabling the device frame. (This Worked for me.)
Step2: If this doesn't work, either change version to lollipop or try giving Ram 2Gb.
Step3: if this still doesn't work, change graphics to Software instead of automatic.

Note:Please check on right side whether Hax file is downloaded while creating new virtual device.

Comment: can you please tell which all given answers you tried?

Comment: everyone unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Select AVD manager
Edit Your Virtual Devices 
Select Graphics to Software-GLES 2.0

Answer (score -1):

- From Android studio open Windows->Select Android Virtual Device Manager->Chose your device->Click Edit button->Change the RAM parameter to 512 Mb in the Memory Options->Save and run the emulator it will work
- Else you may use Genymotion Android Vm: https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download