# Emulator is opening but not running the app

Tags: android, emulation

I have downloaded android studio and now i am trying to run an app.I haven't changed anything in code or design.I am using version 2.2.2 When i click on run it gives me an error
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
But emulator opens.Then there is blank black screen for 2-3 minutes,then androidtitle for another 5 minutes.Then emulator opens,but i don't know where is my app?

Comment: Those immense loading times trigger the question, if your computer has enough resources to run that equipment? Have you installed haxm driver and setup the AVD correctly for the RAM of your machine, chosen the correct android image for your hardware-cpu of the pc, the correct API / Android version image that you want to target? Share your setup please - we cant help without information.
What does the log say? Android Monitor and/or the Run view of Android Studio - there must be a message of some kind.

Comment: I don't have HAXM,RAM is 512 mb,what do you mean correct image and log says `init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!`

Comment: what OS? i cant imagine running a windows machine with 512MB? With correct image i mean, that you set a cpu type for your emulator that should match your physical cpu for performance or a specific cpu that you want to test explicitly (but you dont get acceleration then). haxm is something i'd STRONGLY recommend. the emulator then is as fast as a physical device, if not faster - u can even play games with it.
Regarding the error message: I dont know it. Never had that message, sorry.

Comment: look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio)
It seems already answered.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have `Use Host GPU` checkbox n my version @Grisgram

Comment: @Grisgram I actually have installed HAXM but i have no idea how to use it.It gave me 2 `.exe` files, i ran both of them and either of them was fruitless

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127937/discussion-between-grisgram-and-papaa).