# Android Emulator is not working in Android Studio - giving message Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it

Tags: android, android-emulator

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:

> gles2_dispatch_init: Could not load lib64GLES_V2_translator
>   [lib64GLES_V2_translator.so: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory]
>
> Failed to open lib64EGL_translator: [lib64EGL_translator.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory]
>
> emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library
>   [lib64OpenglRender]: lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory
>
> emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
>
> emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
>
> emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu
>   off' to disable it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9pv9.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have gpu-host enabled and that may cause your error. 
Go to Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager and then uncheck "Use Host GPU".

[image: Location of the setting in AVD]

Comment: I don't have Use Host GPU in AVD , for details click on the https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG9wd.png

Comment: Can you please show a complete screen of ur AVD config panel?

Comment: You can find your answer here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio

Basically you have to select 'Software GLES2.0' option on Emulated Performance and then restart ur AVD.

Comment: Currently it is Software GLES2.0 but not working - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwlZJ.png

Comment: Your image shows Hardware though. Additionally did u restart ur AVD?

Answer (score 1):

edit config file for virtual device

e.g.:

```
C:\Users\<your user>\.android\avd\Nexus_7_API_17.avd\config.ini

...
hw.gpu.enabled=no
...
```