# Android Studio Emulator cannot start

Tags: android-studio

First, I should speak something my questions. When I start the Emulator with Play Store, it cannot run. But when I start the Emulator without Play Store, it can run.

eg:

[image]

Error:

```
10:49   Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString!

10:49   Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

10:49   Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

10:49   Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

10:49   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

10:49   * daemon started successfully

10:49   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

10:49   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: Please go through this link, hope that help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.
I also read the answer to this link before, it is mainly as follows：

Step 1:

Update your Operating system graphics driver.
Restart your system.
Set your system's screen resolution as high as possible.
Try to start your AVD now.
Step 2:

If step 1 fails, Go to AVD Manager.
Edit your AVD.
Uncheck 'Use Host GPU' option.
Click Finish (Save).
Start AVD again.

But my computer cannot start Step2，AVD Manager cannot check "Use Host GPU" setting.
Finaly I only site the Step 1,but Android Studio Emulator has alrealy run.

In addition, I also set up the Android studio program's graphics processor for NVIDIA in the 3D graphics settings of the NVIDIA graphics card.