# Problems launching the emulator in Android Studio.

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to launch the virtual device  on Android Studio, I get the following error:

```html
"C:\Users\Kill me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd ApukaPappu
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Block size: 4096
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inode size: 256
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Journal blocks: 1024
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Label: 
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
    Blocks: 16896
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
    Block groups: 1
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

How can I fix it? 
P.S: I'm new to Android don't have much clue about anything.

Comment: I had the same problem, try my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124858/android-studio-emulator-could-not-find-wglgetextensionsstringarb/40125067#40125067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your gpu drivers might help

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this bcoz of graphics Driver . So  you can `Edit` your `emulator` In `AVD Manager`.
**Steps:**

```
- Edit your AVD.
- Uncheck 'Use Host GPU' option.
- Click Finish (Save).
- Start AVD again.
```

or You can `create` new with `Uncheck 'Use Host GPU'` option.

For more check [myanswer!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567007/cant-start-emulator-for-android-studio/27569946#27569946)
If , Still you have the problem than you have to `update system graphics`.
**Steps:**

```
- Update your Operating system graphics driver.
 - Restart your system.
 - Set your system's screen resolution as high as possible.
 - Try to start your AVD now.Let me know if still you have same prob ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the first answer that you should try updating you graphics card drivers, re-starting and seeing if that works.

Otherwise your error states "ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it." You can do this by:

1. Run AVD Manager (the icon that looks like a phone with a purple screen with an android head popping up towards the end of the line of icons)
2. Select the emulator you are using (e.g. Nexus 5 API 21 x86) and click the pencil icon to edit the configuration.
3. Uncheck "Use Host GPU" in the Emulated Performance section.
4. Click finish and try again.

I'm sure there are performance implications of this option so I would try fixing your drivers first.

Answer (score 0):

Following answer will be for android 2.0 and above users

The error occurs because most computers don't have computer graphic drivers installed. So we have to make it software GLES.

STEPS:

```
1)Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager 
2)Select "Edit" ( a green pencil like icon).
3)Select "Show Advanced Settings".
4)In the Graphics drop list select "Software - GLES 2.0"
5)Click finish to save and now again build the gradle.
```

Below image shows the setting which I had to remove the error.
[image: For further reference]