# Android Studio emulator could not find wglgetextensionsstringarb

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I try to start the emulator, suddenly I started getting this error
[image]

everything worked couple of days ago.
if I disable GPU acceleration then it works but very slowly.

I tried re-enabling virtualization in the bios and it worked once and now I get the same error again..

I have the latest android studio 2.2.1
I have a new graphics card GeForce.

this is the error message

Hax is enabled

init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Hax ram_size 0x60000000

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554

emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554

emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to 
disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED IT!**

it seems to be a screen resolution issue.

I have a 4K laptop but I use 2 regular large screens and the laptop screen if off (lid closed). it seems that my graphics cards detects this and switches to the on board shitty intel card.

the solution is:

1. open laptop lid (so the laptop screen will be on)
2. start emulator
3. once the emulator is running, you can close the laptop lid

or use your graphics cards settings to enable hardware GPU always for AVD (if possible)

Comment: oh god, not this again... this has caught me out in the past too with some virtualisation, thanks for jogging my memory.. exact same issue, worked a treat! :D