# Android emulator is screen is blank

Tags: android

When I open the android emulator, it stays on a black screen.
The app I'm testing is small and basic.

I have the arm* type downloaded, and I set it to 300 RAM, but still nothing.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567007/cant-start-emulator-for-android-studio/27569946#27569946)

Comment: I followed those instructions but it's still a blank screen. I got this message while it was loading though:                                              Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Answer (score 0):

Emulator have many issue if you want good & fast emulator then uses **genymotion** Download from link https://www.genymotion.com/#!/. you will get different type of device and fast devices then emulator.