# Android Emulator won't starting up

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just installed Intel HAXM and updated my Android SDK Tools to revision 24.1.2 successfully. Then I restarted my PC, and ran the emulator. Unfortunately, I my emulator won't starting up, always stuck. Waiting for ~1 hour, the emulator still getting stuck. Sometimes the screen was black, didn't show anything even the ANDROID logo while emulator was booting (full of black color). My screenshot:

[image: adb getting stuck]

The second problem is, as you can see in the figure, this is an abnormal behavior. There's no title bar, because it hides on the top of my desktop. So I can't move the emulator window to the center of my desktop.

From the Console, it seems that Android Studio is waiting for the emulator to finish its start up:

[image: waiting for adb]

What have I tried:

- Restarted my PC.
- Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419712/3922207).
- Check and uncheck *Use host GPU* option in AVD.
- Re-build my emulator in AVD.
- Closed the emulator and ran it again.
- Changed CPU/ABI to ARM and Intel Atom x86 in AVD.

Can you help me to solve these problems?

Comment: Your question concerns an Android Virtual Device (AVD) not the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) as you had originally written.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I read the adb documentation thoroughly, and I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my mom to pray for me to solve these problems, and I found the solution then, hehe :P

So these problems happened because of the skin of emulator I selected in AVD was WQVGA432. Then I changed (edited) the emulator's skin in AVD to WQVGA400 and WQVGA800 to test the result, and it really works for both of them. I think, the only skin which has broken is WQVGA432. If you also had these problems, I suggest you to never select WQVGA432 skin or try another skins.

Now, I can move the emulator window normally and debug my app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a different\more recent Android version?

I suggest you to switch to [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/store).
It's free for personal use and it very better than AVD: it's faster, you can drag and drop files and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Android Studio and re-download the image file from SDK