# Android Emulator Black screen -

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

Application worked on this emulator, I have tried to implement Google Play Game services and it appears that this service can't connect. I have tried on multiple emulators. Now when I run the app all I get is the black screen.

Here is the Android Monitor:

```
09-18 13:11:28.507 1141-1141/? E/Drm: Failed to open plugin directory /vendor/lib/mediadrm
09-18 13:11:29.897 1963-8847/com.google.android.gms E/ChromeSync: [Sync,SyncAdapter] Failed to sync.
                                                                  hlr: Error when calling the server (message: Application credential header not valid. Please fix the client to pass a valid application credential header.).
                                                                      at hlt.b(:com.google.android.gms:11)
                                                                      at hmd.c(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                                                      at hmh.b(:com.google.android.gms:61)
                                                                      at hmf.a(:com.google.android.gms:12)
                                                                      at jlo.onPerformSync(:com.google.android.gms:2)
                                                                      at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
                                                                   Caused by: aury: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Application credential header not valid. Please fix the client to pass a valid application credential header.
                                                                      at auru.c(:com.google.android.gms:2)
                                                                      at jgq.a(:com.google.android.gms:62)
                                                                      at hlt.b(:com.google.android.gms:9)
                                                                      at hmd.c(:com.google.android.gms:1) 
                                                                      at hmh.b(:com.google.android.gms:61) 
                                                                      at hmf.a(:com.google.android.gms:12) 
                                                                      at jlo.onPerformSync(:com.google.android.gms:2) 
                                                                      at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259) 
09-18 13:11:41.977 8863-8863/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-18 13:11:41.977 8863-8863/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-18 13:11:42.887 1963-1972/com.google.android.gms E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                  java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                      at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                      at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:179)
                                                                      at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:168)
                                                                      at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:362)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.n.a(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.n.writeToParcel(:com.google.android.gms:5)
                                                                      at jdq.a(:com.google.android.gms:16)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.d.writeToParcel(:com.google.android.gms:28)
                                                                      at brr.a(:com.google.android.gms:6)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.k.a(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.i.run(:com.google.android.gms:7)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.v.call(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.w.run(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-18 13:11:42.957 1816-2482/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
09-18 13:11:43.397 8903-8903/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
```

Also I tried to install signed **apk** to Emulator with *adb install* but the same problem appears.

Comment: If you haven't done so, check the [dependencies and prerequisites](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#dependencies) in running apps on the Android Emulator. Also, you need to enable adb integration through **Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration**.

Comment: For more information, try to go through [Configure Hardware Acceleration for the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html) and this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device) might also help.