# Emulator gives blank screen with errors in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I am getting blank screen for android emulator in Android Studio 3.0.1. It gives multiple errors as per following screenshots:

[image: Blank screen in emulator]
[image: Errors in Android Studio 3.0.1]

Please let me know if it is issue with the configuration of system or some settings needs to be updated.

Comment: try another emulator and see if you get any changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to Reinstall Emulator with Different configurations & Install HAXM Plugin As Well.

Comment: Tried with different emulators with different configuration. Also, installed HAXM but still it gives blank screen.

Comment: Sometimes its an issue with JDK (Java Development Kit), Also try to Re-install Your Graphics Driver Once. Check out this link It Might help if Problem Persist [Black Screen] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device)