# Is there any way to use android emulator for AMD CPU?

Tags: android, cpu

my CPU doesn't have Virtualization that I can enable it from bios
also I can run another simulators like Nox and no problem.

But if I want run android emulator from android studio, it open but stuck in black screen or just android logo and even after 3 hours not login

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the Android emulator that does not run (black screen) the x86, or the ARM emulator?

Comment: AMD CPU just support ARM, and it's ARM

Comment: Do you have "Use Host GPU" enabled in the emulator? if so, please disable it and try again.

Comment: Yes I did both ways but not work

Comment: Sadly i could not find any sure fix, but others report wildly different solutions for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device