# Android Emulator Black Screen AMD

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

(i spend my 3 to 4 hour for solving my problem from GOOGLE helped)
When i start a emulator it only shows a black screen nothing else ... I also change the GPU Mode but it cannot solved my problem

while using a **AMD** processor
anyone knows its solution

Thanks in Advance  [(Image) Error Shown on Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0RPZ.png)

Comment: increase RAM and Processor or install GenyMotion

Comment: Ram is 6GB  and Processor is also Good

Comment: have you installed it again emulator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator shows nothing except black screen and adb devices shows "device offline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device)

Comment: @bugfreerammohan yes i tried it any time you can see in the picture