# Cant get rid of black screen

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble with this black screen problem for both  emulator and real device.I have tried everything  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022580/android-emulator-shows-nothing-except-black-screen-and-adb-devices-shows-device) And finally  had to reinstall operating system.But problem persists

Edit:I think Its related to my project because.If i create a new project everything is ok

Comment: does it also happen on counter app too? is there any issue `flutter doctor -v` side?

Comment: flutter doctor says Visual studio code not isntalled(But I installed it) :I think Its related to my project because.If i create a new project everything is ok

Comment: well, you may try checking material app and scaffold  on top widget.