AOSP 6 build and start emulator black window
before action : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78324271/7707781
new problem
Now i'm on intel macOs
I build aosp6 success by docker .
terminal docker and run `$AOSP_PATH/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/emulator` the emulator could be lunch success .
then close the emulator by click windows button .
try next lunch the emulator , run `$AOSP_PATH/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/emulator` just black screen windows .
I have try two way :

[not resolve] rm -rf `~/.android`

compaire success and black window logs , Almost the same as no exception found


diff --git a/emulator.21.success.log b/emulator.22.try.log
index a654a6a..7bf0090 100644
--- a/emulator.21.success.log
+++ b/emulator.22.try.log
@@ -1,130 +1,129 @@
 emulator: found Android build root: /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1
 emulator: found Android build out:  /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic
 emulator: Read property file at /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system/build.prop
 emulator: Cannot find boot properties file: /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/boot.prop

 emulator: Found target API sdkVersion: 23

 emulator: virtual device has no config file - no problem
 emulator: using core hw config path: /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/hardware-qemu.ini
 emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
 emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
 emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/development/tools/emulator/skins
 emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
 emulator: writing default keyset file to /Users/tom/.android/default.keyset
-emulator: write_default_keyset: could not create file: No such file or directory
 emulator: trying to load skin file '/Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/layout'
 emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
 emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
 emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu-armv7
 emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
 emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
 emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img
 emulator: autoconfig: -sysdir /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic
 emulator: Using initial system image: /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system.img
 emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (1536 MB > 200 MB)

 emulator: autoconfig: -data /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/userdata-qemu.img
 emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/userdata.img
 emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file (550 MB > 200 MB)

 emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/cache.img
 emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

 emulator: GPU emulation is disabled
 emulator: WARNING: CPU acceleration only works with x86/x86_64 system images.
 emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu cortex-a8
 Content of hardware configuration file:
   hw.cpu.arch = arm
   hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
   hw.ramSize = 512
   hw.screen = touch
   hw.mainKeys = yes
   hw.trackBall = yes
   hw.keyboard = no
   hw.keyboard.lid = no
   hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
   hw.dPad = yes
   hw.gsmModem = yes
   hw.gps = yes
   hw.battery = yes
   hw.accelerometer = yes
   hw.audioInput = yes
   hw.audioOutput = yes
   hw.sdCard = yes
   disk.cachePartition = yes
   disk.cachePartition.path = /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/cache.img
   disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
   hw.lcd.width = 320
   hw.lcd.height = 480
   hw.lcd.depth = 16
   hw.lcd.density = 160
   hw.lcd.backlight = yes
   hw.gpu.enabled = no
   hw.initialOrientation = portrait
   hw.camera.back = emulated
   hw.camera.front = none
   vm.heapSize = 48
   hw.sensors.proximity = yes
   hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
   hw.sensors.orientation = yes
   hw.sensors.temperature = yes
   hw.useext4 = yes
   kernel.path = /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu-armv7
   kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1
   kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
   kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
   disk.ramdisk.path = /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img
   disk.systemPartition.initPath = /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system.img
   disk.systemPartition.size = 1536m
   disk.dataPartition.path = /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/userdata-qemu.img
   disk.dataPartition.size = 550m
   avd.name = <build>
 .
 QEMU options list:
 emulator: argv[00] = "/Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/emulator64-arm"
 emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
 emulator: argv[02] = "/Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/hardware-qemu.ini"
 Concatenated QEMU options:
  /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/emulator64-arm -android-hw /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/hardware-qemu.ini
 emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
 emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
 emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
 emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
 emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
 emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
 emulator: system partition format: ext4
-emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to /tmp/android-tom/emulator-fMZR2U
-emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x60000000,file=/tmp/android-tom/emulator-fMZR2U,initfile=/Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
+emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to /tmp/android-tom/emulator-EpGUj4
+emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x60000000,file=/tmp/android-tom/emulator-EpGUj4,initfile=/Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
 emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
 emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x22600000,file=/Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/userdata-qemu.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
 emulator: cache partition format: ext4
 emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
 emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
 emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
 emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.config.low_ram' = 'true'
 emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
 emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
 emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
 emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1 ndns=2
 emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
 emulator: Forcing ro.adb.qemud to "0".
 emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
 emulator: can't connect to ADB server: Socket is not connected (errno = 57)
 emulator: setting up http proxy:  server=127.0.0.1 port=8889
 emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

 emulator: ping program: /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/ddms
 goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:170: display surface,pixel format:
   bits/pixel:  16
   bytes/pixel: 2
   depth:       16
   red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
   green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
   blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
   alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
 emulator: ### WARNING: /etc/localtime does not point to /usr/share/zoneinfo/, can't determine zoneinfo timezone name
 emulator: _hwFingerprint_connect: connect finger print listen is called

 emulator: got message from guest system fingerprint HAL








I'm on Intel mac

Resolve link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46561887/7707781
try wipe data , my option command

the failed command :    emulatorAlias -verbose
the success command :  emulatorAlias -verbose  -wipe-data 


Many times -wipe-data option is not work good .
Restart computer always resolve emulator run with black screen problem.
Another thing: When the emulator black screen is not mean emulator not start , just view is black  . because try adb shell ps is success return result process list .
